# In Google Script, get the spreadsheet cell calling a custom function

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-custom-function

In VBA for Excel, I can get the column of the cell making the call to a custom function like this:

`ThisCol = Application.Caller.Column`

What is the equivalent in Google Scripts?
I've been trying to find my way through the API docs, but coming up empty....

I call this function in a cell in each row of a range.  The function sums contents of a range of cells across the row.  Here's the VB:

```
Public Function SumDays(row As Integer)

  Dim credit As Double

  NumCols = Range("D8", Range("D8").End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count
  ThisRow = row
  ThisCol = Application.Caller.Column  ' column containing the cell calling the fn

  credit = 0

  For i = (ThisCol + 3) To NumCols
     'do stuff across the range of cols in ThisRow
     ' If Cells(ThisRow, i) = ....
  Next i

  SumDays = credit
End Function
```

Comment: Perhaps you can show us what you want to do, then we can show you how to do it? Sharing a doc is also very helpful.

Comment: Added VB script and some more explanation.

Comment: If you share a doc, and show us your expected result, then I will edit my post and give you the full code.

Answer (score 9):

The answer to your first question is:

### Code

```
function test() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getColumn(); 
}
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Remark

Add the code under Tools>Script editor and press the save button.

### Example

I've prepared an example file for you: **[sample GAS code](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdHFIQ0hjbXJFTGZBZ3pHVlR3YVV1dWc&usp=sharing)**

Comment: Should this still work? If I run getColumn from within a cell it always returns 1, regardless of which cell.

Comment: @Punchlinern tried naming the function into `getColumn()` and `test()` and both returned the desired result. Added an example file.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra - It seams to be an issue with the New Google Spreadsheets. It's working when I check your example file, and if create a new file with the new features turned off. Still not my files created in New Google Spreadsheet.

Comment: This worked fine for me I have used it with `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getValue()`

Comment: This is wrong answer, because when saved document starts again active cell is A1, when calling custom function can be anywhere else.

Comment: This code gets the active cell (i.e. the user selected cell) - it does not answer the question "how do I get the column of the cell making a call to a custom function?".

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra this might be an old answer but still solves my issue (partially).. calling an appScript function from a cell works perfect, now, what can I do to run it programmatically?? I might write a new question in SO

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/150722/in-google-spreadsheet-run-a-function-from-cell-programmatically