# In Google Spreadsheet run a function from cell programmatically

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-custom-function

I made an Apps Script custom function in a Google spreadsheet.

I can call it from a cell and works fine ([In Google Script, get the spreadsheet cell calling a custom function](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54414/in-google-cript-get-the-spreadsheet-cell-calling-a-custom-function)).

The function makes an API call to retrieve some information from the web. The data changes constantly, so I'd like to execute the function programmatically. I tried using triggers, but the only options I get when choosing the source "from a spreadsheet" are "when open", "when close" or "when change". Then, there is another source for choosing a programmatically call, but executes the function itself, not the one I call from the cell.

I want the value of the cell to be updated each XX seconds (a period of time).

NOTE: My function fetches a value from a free Web API, so I need it to fetch it using an interval of time, let's say every 5 seconds

Answer (score 1):

In your [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/150722/in-google-spreadsheet-run-a-function-from-cell-programmatically#comment137404_150734) you mention about an: *"...interval of time, let's say every 5 seconds"*

This is not possible.

Please check the [Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)
 for further info.

```
Triggers total runtime  | 90 min / day  | 6 hr / day
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to fetch a value and add it to a Google Sheets cell every few seconds from a Web API by using Google Apps Script is using client side code to call a server side function. One way to do this is by using a sidebar and [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to execute  `google.script.run` periodically.

This will work while the user account doesn't exceed the [Google Apps Script quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).

---

There are two ways to force a custom function to recalculate:

1. Change the value of one of it's parameters
2. Copy the formula, clear the cell, "flush" and add again the formula

The easier is one as you can use set a time driven trigger to change the value of a cell used as a custom function parameter.

```
=myFunction(arg1,arg2, B1)
```

Every time that B1 changes, `myFunction` will be recalculated (please note that custom functions cant't use `NOW()`, `RAND()`, `RANDBETWEEN()` as arguments.

The other method by "flush" I mean using `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` before adding again the formula.

Unfortunately the shortest period of time for a time driven trigger is one minute.

Related

- [How to display a current cell value in sidebar without reload the sidebar?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57359551/1595451)

Comment: Thank you @Rubén but it's not what I need. My function fetches a value from a free Web API, so I need it to fetch it using an interval of time, let's say every 5 seconds

Comment: @RodrigoE.Principe I updated my answer